# Box that behaves like vbox but its width is that of its content?

Tags: boxes, varwidth

I need a box that fulfils these conditions:

1. It can contain multiple lines (and paragraphs) of text (unlike `\hbox`)
2. A line that is longer then `\textwidth` is split to the next line (like `\parbox`, `\vbox` and unlike `\hbox`, `\mbox`)
3. The content of the box is surrounded closely. That is width of the box is automatically set to width of content (like `\hbox`, unlike `\vbox` and `\parbox`). Because of 3. width of box should actually be minimum of `\textwidth` and width of box content. Height is height of box content.

How can I get such a behaviour?

Answer (score 34):

The environment `varwidth` from the package of the same name needs only a length which will be the maximum of the allowed box width

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{varwidth}    
\begin{document}

\fbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
some text
\end{varwidth}}

\fbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{\textwidth}
some more text to see if there can be a line break at the end
of the line with this nonsense text
\end{varwidth}}

\fbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
some text
\end{varwidth}}

\fbox{%
\begin{varwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
some more text to see if there can be a line break at the end
of the line with this nonsense text
\end{varwidth}}

\end{document}
```

[image]