# How to calc the width of environment by using box-module in LaTeX3?

Tags: latex3

### Question

I came to a question that : How to calc the width of a environment or a paragraph by LaTeX3?

### What I have done

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_calc_width_box
\dim_new:N \l_calc_width_dim
\cs_new:Npn \calcwidth:n #1
    {
        \the\linewidth
        \vbox_set:Nw \l_calc_width_box { #1 } \vbox_set_end:
        \dim_set:Nn \l_calc_width_dim { \box_wd:N \l_calc_width_box } \par
        \dim_use:N \l_calc_width_dim
        #1
    }
\calcwidth:n {test}

\calcwidth:n 
    {
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 
            \item 
            \item 
        \end{enumerate}
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

My idea is that

1. store what I want to measure in a box
2. calc the width of the box
3. store the width in a dim variable

### Problems I met

1. If I store the `content` in a vbox, then the width of it is the current linewidth;
2. If I store the `content` in a hbox, then

- I couldn't use some environments like `enumerate` as the `content` which will get issues
- hbox is always horizontal: If use `\box_wd:N` to get the width of it, it'll goes up without limitation as the `content` become more and more

### What I want

1. I want to know if I can do it by using box module.
2. If there are any other better ways in LaTeX3 to get the width or height of the content, which may include environment, easily.
3. To make my desire more clear, I use a picture:
   [image]

I want to calculate the width of the **red** part but not the **blue** part

Comment: Take a look at the `varwidth` package for reference on how to do such things.

Comment: It's written by TeX, which I didn't know too much, it's hard for me to understand..

Comment: the width of a box with vertical material is always what you set `\hsize` to be (eg `\linewidth` once you have a list). hboxes have a natural width but vertical material is line broken to a specified width, even witha short text like `test` the width of the box is not at the red line, white space is added to each line to make it full width. compare tables have lcr natural width 1-line columns and `p{..}` fixed width columns. to do what you want you need something like `varwidth` or `tabular` that makes multiple trial settings at different widths and finds a width that makes a suitable setting.

Comment: The LaTeX3 programming layer is written in TeX as well. And if you want to do this with LaTeX2e constructs you'll have to alter said LaTeX2e constructs to make it work. Or you do `\hbox_set:Nn \l_xdyy_calc_width_box { \begin{varwidth}{\hsize} #1 \end{varwidth} }` and measure the width of that.

Comment: Thank you so much, by using varwidth environment in the box setting, I get what I want exactly !

Comment: @xdyy By the way — while the *inner code* of a package written using LaTeX2e interface can be hard to understand, the *external interface* should be easy to understand. (it's just an environment that you can use.) As you can see in this example.

Comment: "See also" [boxes - Box that behaves like vbox but its width is that of its content? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91416/box-that-behaves-like-vbox-but-its-width-is-that-of-its-content)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks so much, I will update my opinion :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `varwidth` package inside your LaTeX3 code. While not perfect style this is fine as long as there is no LaTeX3 interface for what you want. The `varwidth` package allows to specify a maximum width for a box, but yields a box less wide if possible.

You can interface it from within your code by nesting it inside a `\hbox_set:Nn`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{varwidth}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \l_xdyy_width_dim
\box_new:N \l__xdyy_calc_width_box
\NewDocumentCommand \calcwidth { m }
  {
    \xdyy_calc_width:Nn \l_xdyy_width_dim {#1}
    \dim_use:N \l_xdyy_width_dim
    \par
    \fbox { \box_use:N \l__xdyy_calc_width_box }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xdyy_calc_width:Nn #1#2
  {
    \hbox_set:Nn \l__xdyy_calc_width_box
      { \begin{varwidth} { \hsize } #2 \end{varwidth} }
    \dim_set:Nn #1 { \box_wd:N \l__xdyy_calc_width_box }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\calcwidth{test}

\calcwidth
  {%
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item abc
      \item def
    \end{enumerate}
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for making a full answer, I'll use it in my code.