# How to get the width of the environment newed by lstnewenvironment?

Tags: listings, environments

### Background

I tried to new a environment to show the LaTeX code and the result compiled together. I referenced the [siunitx.tex](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/a00ba7040638077b16f975b3113ad0baf03ab683/siunitx.tex#L90=L160) and made a MWE as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% For creating code demonstrations
% This needs access to some code-level interfaces in listings
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}
\newsavebox\LaTeXdemo@box
\lstnewenvironment{LaTeXdemo}[1][code and example]
  {%
    \global\let\lst@intname\@empty
    \edef\LaTeXdemo@end{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname LaTeXdemo@@#1@end\endcsname
    }%
    \@nameuse{LaTeXdemo@@#1}%
  }
  {\LaTeXdemo@end}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\LaTeXdemo@new[3]{%
  \@namedef{LaTeXdemo@@#1}{#2}%
  \@namedef{LaTeXdemo@@#1@end}{#3}%
}
\newcommand*\LaTeXdemo@common{%
  \setkeys{lst}
    {%
            basicstyle         = \ttfamily\small,
            basewidth          = 0.51em,
            backgroundcolor    = \color{cyan!10},
            % rulecolor          = \color{red!10},
            frame              = shadowbox,
            frameround         = tttt,
            % framerule          = 0pt,
            gobble             = 4,
            tabsize            = 2,
            numbers            = left,
            language           = [LaTeX]TeX,
            % linewidth          = 0.5\linewidth
    }%
}
\newcount\LaTeXdemo@count
\newcommand*\LaTeXdemo@input{%
  \catcode`\^^M = 10\relax
  \input{\jobname-\number\LaTeXdemo@count.tmp}%
}
\LaTeXdemo@new{code and example}{%
  \setbox\LaTeXdemo@box=\hbox\bgroup
    \global\advance\LaTeXdemo@count by 1 %
    \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname-\number\LaTeXdemo@count.tmp}%
    \LaTeXdemo@common
}{%
    \lst@EndWriteFile
  \egroup
  \begin{center}
    \ifdim\wd\LaTeXdemo@box > 0.48\linewidth
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \usebox\LaTeXdemo@box
      \end{minipage}%
      \par
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \LaTeXdemo@input
      \end{minipage}
    \else
      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \LaTeXdemo@input
      \end{minipage}%
      \hfil
      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \usebox\LaTeXdemo@box
      \end{minipage}%
    \fi
  \end{center}
}
\LaTeXdemo@new{code and float}{%
  \global\advance\LaTeXdemo@count by 1 %
  \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname-\number\LaTeXdemo@count.tmp}%
  \LaTeXdemo@common
}{%
  \lst@EndWriteFile
  \LaTeXdemo@input
}
\LaTeXdemo@new{code only}{\LaTeXdemo@common}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{LaTeXdemo}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item 1
            \item 2
            \item 3
            \item 4
            \item 5
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{LaTeXdemo}
\end{document}
```

### Problem

The MWE worked well. But when I wanted to color the code part, I found it too long:
[image]

So I use the `linewidth` to adjust it. Then I thought: why not calculate the width by itself? Then I want to use LaTeX3 to calc the width as I always do.

But! Here is the problem:
**`lstnewenvironment` just like `newenvironment` : the code doesn't contain the `BODY` part as `environ` does, so I was unable to measure the width.**

So is there any ways to get the body of the `lstnewenvironment`? Then I can store it into the box and get the width of it.

### Problem Summary

Thanks @user202729 for reminding me of `\LaTeXdemo@box` contain the content, I did measure the width, but I fail to set the width, it seems that the content has been fixed,  although I get the width of it, the lstset didn't effect it at all.

Comment: What exactly do you want to measure the width of? (the inner part in monospace or the whole thing? The whole thing doesn't make sense because it overflows anyway?)

Comment: I wan to measure the **content（or the body**) of `LaTeXdemo` env. In the MWE, it's "\begn{enumerate} ... \end{enuerate}"

Comment: Your MWE should be edited to include the colorized version.

Comment: Ah, I see. Pretty much [boxes - Box that behaves like vbox but its width is that of its content? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91416/box-that-behaves-like-vbox-but-its-width-is-that-of-its-content) . (or [How to calc the width of environment by using box-module in LaTeX3? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627624/how-to-calc-the-width-of-environment-by-using-box-module-in-latex3?noredirect=1&lq=1) which already uses LaTeX3.)

Comment: Ah, you need *both* varwidth to measure and some way to get the inner content, I see. Then use `scontents` in addition.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Thanks for reminding me of that, I have edited it.

Comment: @user202729 
Maybe I didn't explain it quite well. I do **know how to measure** sth by LaTeX3, but the only thing I couldn't do is to **get the BODY of lstnewenvironment**, let alone measure the width.
I didn't get it about `scontents`, could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: Wait, actually you don't need that... didn't you *already have* the content of the body (in the file `\jobname-\number\LaTeXdemo@count.tmp`)?

Comment: @user202729
Thanks for reminding me of that, I've tried but I did measure the width, but I fail to set the width, it seems that the content has been fixed,  although I get the width of it, the lstset didn't effect it at all.